# Unresolved reference when upgrading project from Gradle 3.6.0 to 8.2.2

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
import com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.extra


fun ExtraPropertiesExtension.string(key: String): String = (get(key) as String)

fun ExtraPropertiesExtension.int(key: String): Int = (get(key) as String).toInt()

fun BuildType.buildConfigString(name: String, value: String) =
    buildConfigField("String", name, "\"$value\"")


fun Project.configureAndroid(android: BaseExtension) {
    val properties = listOf("android.compileSdkVersion", "android.minSdkVersion", "android.targetSdkVersion", "android.versionCode")
    val found = properties.map { extra.has(it) }
    require(found.all { it }) { "Missing some properties=$properties => found=$found" }
    val versions = properties.map { p -> extra.int(p) }

    android.compileSdkVersion(versions[0])
    android.defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(versions[1])
        targetSdkVersion(versions[2])
        versionCode = versions[3]
        versionName = extra.string("android.versionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled = true
    }


    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

fun Project.configureBuildConfig(android: BaseExtension) {
    android.buildTypes.all {
        resValue("string", "baseUrl", extra.string("chrome.baseUrl"))
        buildConfigString("baseUrl", extra.string("chrome.baseUrl"))
        resValue("string", "baseHostname", extra.string("chrome.baseHostname"))
        buildConfigString("baseHostname", extra.string("chrome.baseHostname"))
        resValue("string", "pusherInstanceId", extra.string("pusher.instanceId"))
        buildConfigString("pusherInstanceId", extra.string("pusher.instanceId"))
        resValue("string", "userAgent", extra.string("chrome.userAgent"))
        buildConfigString("userAgent", extra.string("chrome.userAgent"))
    }
}
```

When upgrading the projecto to java 19 and gradle 8.2.2
import com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType

are not longer available, where are those references located in the newer versions of gradle, or where can I look for, I'm new to Android

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. It seems that it shows partially the Gradle config you have included as text, so it is just redundant info which can confuse people who read your question.